# IEnumerable Count Performance

Tags: .net

I have a dataset of a database call and a resultset of in-memory dataset. I am looping through my in-memory dataset and getting count from the database results. The problem I'm facing here is that I noticed the Count performance is somewhat annoying. The database call return withing 1-2 seconds for 10000 records, however the operation on the Count takes over 4 seconds.

I even tried Parallel.Foreach, but that didn't seem to help much. 
UPDATE:

```
var DBresult = context.tables.ToList();
var InMemory = List<MyClass>();//let's assume I have 100 items

foreach(var item in InMemory)
{
item.count1 = DBresult.Where(item.somefilter).Count(),
item.count2 = DBresult.Where(item.somefilter2).Count()
.....//more count
}
```

**2nd Update:**
It seems like I need to clarify a few concerns with how I do what I do. I use LinqKit to help me build dynamic Expression. In some simple case, it works wonderful - but not the case for complex ones. In this example, I have defined a list of "MyClass" let's say "history,math,science". In each of these classes, I have a different way of counting students. 
For history class, badstudent = students with grade < C and 65% attendance. 
Math class, badstudent = students with grade < D and 50% attendance.
I do understand I have a choice to write a stored proc and make it work. However, I'm trying to declare my filters this way because they are being used across other projects in my solution. It is easier to maintain and reuse. I'm willing to accept the cost of doing ".ToList()" vs writing stored proc. As I indicated above, it is not the DB performance that caused slowness.

Comment: What is the type of `item.somefilter`? Is it a `Func`? Or an `Expression`?

Comment: It is type Expression, so it can be used in IQueryable and IEnumerable.

Comment: This wouldn't compile. `DBresult` is of type `List<T>` and therefore `Where` in this case can only take in a `Func`, not an `Expression`.

Comment: The codes above were meant for simplicity. Of course an Expression is called in IEnumber<T>, I need to do .Comile(). `item.count2=DBresult.Where(item.somefilter2.Compile()).Count();`

Comment: So, don't call `Compile` and don't call `ToList()` on `context.tables`.

Comment: I wish it was that simple. I have a "in-memory" dataset that I need for the filtering. Entity Framework doesn't support in-memory join with dbcontext. That is why I had to do .ToList() first and loop through my in-memory dataset.